# Returning jQuery click function css change back

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

I have this jQuery call for a dropdown. On click, the background image of an inner container changes its background image. How do I change the background image for the inner container back?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#listH1').click(function () {
    $('#content1').slideToggle('medium');
    $(".span").css("background-image","url(carrow.png)");  
  });
});
```

Comment: The first question would be what do you want to trigger the action of changing it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

**CSS**

```
.yourNewBackground {
    background-image: url(carrow.png);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#listH1').click(function () {
    $('#content1').slideToggle('medium');
    $(".span").toggleClass("yourNewBackground");
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zYMn7/1/). A couple things to note:

- When working with a fiddle, make sure you select the appropriate framework. You had MooTools selected (the default), instead of jQuery.
- `toggleClass()` wasn't working because of the `span` class. Adding `!important` to the `toggleDown` class was all that was needed.

Comment: @Jamal_Jakson, did you properly create the CSS class? Have you tested the class to ensure that you've set it up properly?

Comment: Here are both classes

.span{width:100%;background-image:   url(../images/carrow1.png);background-position: 1% 0%;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:13px 13px;display: block;height:17px;margin-top:15px;float:left;}

.toggleDown{background-image: url(../images/carrow.png);}

Comment: @Jamal_Jakson, can you post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Here is a link to my site, its a mobile thing so it will not render 100% properly styling wise if browser isn't set to the right width.
http://bkvdigital.com/dev.techops/capabilites/default.html

Comment: @Jamal_Jakson, a fiddle allows us to play with the code, determine the issue, and modify the code so that we can provide a working example.

Comment: It wasn't working at all in fiddle. That is why I just gave you the link, and I have other things needed to be done to the site this is for right now.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I honestly don't see it.

Comment: Im so blind, lol. I actually thought you were talking about in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

If the background is set in a style sheetfile, you can just delete the custom `style`-attribute you created there:

```
$(".span").css('background-image', '');
```

Comment: I put this before my css change?